# How make divs float like this

Tags: css

I've a little question about a few divs, how to make this:
[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/21o6jw3.jpg]

If I use `float:left;` needs to have same width or height.. I tried this on a old website but doesn't work with float left.

I want that divs to be near with same margins but without depends by w and h.

So, how can I do that?

I saw in isotope plugin it's using position absolute, but how to implement this i don't know

Comment: With absolute-positioning, there would be a script which would take the measurements of all of the elements and lay them out according to an algorithm, so this couldn't be done with pure-CSS.

Comment: You could use Masonry.js